# Variable visible in $scope but undefined when actually accessed in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

In Angular, I have a variable `var1` which is defined in an `ng-init` (I am aware that this isn't recommended practice).

From my controller, if I do `console.log($scope)`, I can see the variable `var1` with its initialised value. If I `console.log($scope.var1)`, I find that it is `undefined`

```
app.controller('app', function($scope) {
    console.log($scope); // var1 appears here with it's initialised value
    console.log($scope.var1); // this is undefined
});
```

Why might the first log show the initialised variable but the second not?

----- EDIT ------

Note if I do

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log($scope.var1);
}, 0);
```

then `var1` is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be occurring because you're trying to access the variable even before it's assigned a value by angular.

> 1. try putting your console statement in a timeout.
> 2. Avoid using ng-init for initializations.